# What's constitute an entry on the IPTables and how to find out which client it is originated from

Tags: iptables

I have a Billion BiPac 7700N Modem/Router/Access Point and I connect another router (TP-Link TL-WR1043ND) in wan-bypass mode to extend the wireless coverage. Lately, I noticed that the connection through TP-Link has been dropping out quite regularly.

Having read some posts on the Internet, I checked system log on 7700N and found that there are many "nf_conntract: expectation table full" errors, which I suppose the iptables are full.

My questions:

1. What does constitute an entry on the iptable? Is it a client or a connection (which means one client can have multiple connections)
2. How could I find out where are those connections originated from?

Note: Many reported that the issue is usually related to having torrents running but I don't have any torrents running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entry in the (expectation/regular) tracking table is a connection. You may have several from the same client.

On Linux you can check the expectation table content (and see where they come from) with:

```
sudo conntrack -L expect
```

But this conntrack tool is usually not installed by default (on Ubuntu you need to install the conntrack package). I don't know if you can install it on these modem/routers you have.

From the man page of conntrack:

> Connection tracking expectations are 
>    the mechanism used to  "expect"  RELATED  connections to existing  ones. 
>    Expectations are generally used by "connection tracking helpers" (sometimes 
>   called application level gateways [ALGs]) for more complex protocols such as 
>   FTP, SIP, H.323.

So it's not any connection which is causing you trouble, it is a connection from a more complex protocol which needs a connection tracking helper (which I think is the case of torrents and several others P2P protocols).

Comment: Also, you could check the status of `nf_conntrack_expect_max` with `sysctl net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_expect_max`. If it's low and you still have RAM left, you can tune it to a higher value, e.g. by `sysctl -w net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_expect_max=128`. However, watch out, it eats memory. Funny, I've never seen this table running full, usually `ip_conntrack_max` comes first.

Comment: Thank you for your response dgmorales and Alexander Janssen. Is there anyway to tell which client makes how many connection?

Comment: @cbd you could grep the output of `sudo conntrack -L expect` for the client IP. Also, if it's feasible to check each client machine you can use netstat on them.

Comment: I've just discovered the files `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` and `/proc/net/ip_conntrack_expect`, which seem to have the same information that `conntrack -L` outputs.  Look for these files on your router, @cbd. You could grep them instead.